# python: использование позитивного просмотра назад и позитивного просмотра вперед

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения, re

Необходимо в python в выражениях найти блоки +-*/(цифры#!)+-*/ (ну или от начала или от конца строки) и удалить () оставив начинку внутри

делаю так:

использую регулярное выражение

```
(?<=[-+*%\/]|^)(\(([0-9!#]+)\))(?=[-+*%\/]|$)
```

в коде

```
print(re.sub(r'(?<=[-+*%\/]|^)(\(([0-9!#]+)\))(?=[-+*%\/]|$)', r'\2', txt))
```

и получаю ошибку

```
raise error("look-behind requires fixed-width pattern")
re.error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern
```

что не так с шаблоном и как его использовать корректно для данной задачи или как его переделать?

условно чтобы

```
(12!)*(7!)+9
```

превратилось в

```
12!*7!+9
```

Comment: Нужно найти все скобки ( и ) удалить их?

Comment: вы бы пример строки для парсинга привели. из вопроса не понятно - это у вас исходная строка такая или псевдокод.

Comment: @Amgarak, да, но только те, за которыми ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО стоят арифметические операции +*-/ (или начало и конец строки), а внутри только цифры и !#

Comment: @strawdog, пример я привел - (12!)*(7!)+9 - такая исходная строка

Comment: `print(re.sub(r'([-+*%\/]|^)(\(([0-9!#]+)\))(?=[-+*%\/]|$)', r'\1\3', txt))` - просмотр назад не нужен, если вы можете этот кусок вставить обратно при замене.

Comment: просмотр назад нужен был чтобы обнаружить именно ситуацию знаки скобки знаки иначе попадают и другие ситуации

Comment: Покажите пример, который неправильно работает с предыдущим регулярным выражением.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy, проверил, все ок, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Эта проблема и её решения описаны мной на английском StackOverflow [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40617321/3832970).

[Модуль регулярных выражений PyPi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40617321/3832970), устанавливаемый с помощью `pip install regex` (или `pip3 install regex`), решает данную проблему целиком и полностью, так как поддерживает шаблоны любой длины в блоке предварительного просмотра назад.

В регулярных выражениях библиотеки `re` шаблон предварительного просмотра назад действительно должен иметь фиксированную длину. Когда внутри него есть чередования различной длины, есть несколько решений этой проблемы.

- Перепишите шаблон так, чтобы вам не приходилось использовать чередование. Если шаблон в просмотре назад представляет собой чередование "якоря" с одним символом (*как в текущем вопросе*), вы можете изменить знак просмотра назад и использовать отрицательный класс символов с символом внутри. Например, `(?<=\s|^)\w+(?=\s|$)` обычно можно записать  с помощью двойного отрицания как `(?<!\S)\w+(?!\S)`. `(?<=\s|^)` находит либо пробел, либо начало строки. В библиотеке `re` вместо него используйте `(?<!\S)`. `(?<=^|;)` можно преобразовать в `(?<![^;])` (при тестировании на онлайн-сайтах добавьте `\n` к классу отрицательных символов, например `(?<![^;\n]`)
- Разделите чередования внутри блока предварительного просмотра на отдельные блоки предварительного просмотра:

  - Позитивные просмотры назад необходимо чередовать в группе (например, `(?<=a|bc)` следует переписать как `(?:(?<=a)|(?<=bc))`)
  - Отрицательные результаты просмотра можно поместить один за другим (например, `(?<!^|,)"(?!,|$)` должен выглядеть как `(?<!^)(?<!,)"(?!,|$)`).

**Ответ**

Вы можете использовать

```
(?<![^-+*%/])(\(([0-9!#]+)\))(?![^-+*%/])
```

См. [пример работы выражения](https://regex101.com/r/YsXhgO/1) (в тесте добавлен знак переноса строки, который будет полезен при тестировании сразу нескольких строк).